# Include a text field inside an alert dialog

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

When a user clicks an "Add" button, I would like an alert dialog to be shown to the user, allowing them to enter in a store number into an entry field. I have researched into this but have not found any clear solution regarding this for Xamarin.Forms.

View my code below on what I have tried. I added an entry field in my Xaml and made it invisible. Then I added a tap gesture so that once my FAB is tapped, the entry field now becomes visible in the alert dialog. This does not work though.

Xaml:

```
<Image
    Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
    Source="add.png"
    HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
    Margin="0,0,30,30"
    HeightRequest="45"
    WidthRequest="45">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer 
            Command="{Binding clickNewCard}"
            CommandParameter="3"
            Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>          
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>

<Entry x:Name="StoreField" InputTransparent="True" IsVisible="False"/>
```

Xaml.cs

```
private async void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (e != null)
    {
        StoreField.IsVisible = true;
        await DisplayAlert("Enter Store Number", StoreField.Text, "Add");
    }        
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup maybe help .

Comment: Thanks @ColeXia , great plugin!

Comment: [Acr.UserDialogs](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs) has some cool extensions too. Alerts, Prompts, Loading Indicators, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As @Cole_Xia mentioned there are a couple of NuGet packages you can use to create custom Alert dialogs with Xamarin Forms for example:

1.- https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup

2.- https://github.com/michaeled/FormsPopup

3.- https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs

I have tried Forms Popup and it definitely works.